# How to create a low memory consumption snap to grid canvas system HTML + JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

What I'm trying to do (which I've been able to accomplish, but with poor performances) is to apply a sort of grid over the canvas, in order to be able to take inputs from the user about the origin point position. Once the input is received, the "draw" coordinates are provided via keyboard.

What I've managed to do in these days, was to calculate the width and height of the canvas, then divide it by the area of a standard 20x20 square (speaking in px). In this way I can loop on the result and create n squares, that I will render in display flex inside the grid element. Then this grid element is applied "over" the canvas.

Everything works, but there's a lot of divs going around, and if the user choses to shrink the div to let's say 10x10, then, that would have a great impact over the performances... So I'm trying to find out a lighter way to do this...

I've thought about using HR elements inside two divs that would be applied over the canvas. One div displays elements in column, and another in row. In this way I should obtain the grid, but what about the snap? How could I detect the intersection on the two HR elements and use that exact spot as position?

The reason of why I cannot directly draw the grid on the canvas is because this should remain as 'pure' as possible. Containing only the final draw of the user.

#### Here's the 'non optimized' code:

I'm using Angular 5 as framework.

```
<div class="draw-zone" #drawZone>
    <div class="grid" #grid [ngClass]="{'activated': activateDrawZones}">
        <div *ngFor="let block of gridBlocks" class="grid-block" [ngClass]="{'show': showGrid, 'ten-x-ten': blockSize === 10, 'twe-x-twe': blockSize === 20, 'thr-x-thr': blockSize === 30, 'fou-x-fou': blockSize === 40}"
            #gridBlock (click)="draw($event, gridBlock)"></div>
    </div>
    <canvas #canvas [height]="canvasSize.y" [width]="canvasSize.x"></canvas>
</div>
```

#### The scss:

```
.draw-zone{
    flex-grow: 2;   
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    canvas{
        z-index: 10;
    }

    .grid{
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 11;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: -.1rem;
        border-radius: .5rem;
        align-content: stretch;
        border: 1px solid transparent;

        &.activated{
            border-color: #3f51b5;
        }

        .grid-block{
            opacity: 0;
            border-right: 1px solid #3f51b5;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #3f51b5;

            &.show{
                opacity: .1;
            }

            &:hover{
                opacity: 1;
                border-radius: 50%;
                background-color: #3f51b5;
                transform: scale(1.2);
            }

            &.ten-x-ten{
                width: 10px;
                height: 10px;
            }
            &.twe-x-twe{
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
            }
            &.thr-x-thr{
                width: 30px;
                height: 30px;
            }
            &.fou-x-fou{
                width: 40px;
                height: 40px;
            }
        }
    }
```

#### And the component method to cal:

```
private calculateGrid() {
    this.activateDrawZones = false;

    this.canvasSize.x = this._drawZone.nativeElement.clientWidth;
    this.canvasSize.y = this._drawZone.nativeElement.clientHeight;
    const blocksCount = (this.canvasSize.x * this.canvasSize.y) / (this.blockSize * this.blockSize);

    this.gridBlocks = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < blocksCount; i++) {
        this.gridBlocks.push({ size: this.blockSize });
    }

    this.activateDrawZones = true;
}
```

#### And the method that actually draws:

```
public draw(e: MouseEvent, block: HTMLDivElement, returnOnFail?: boolean) {
    const x = block.offsetLeft + (this.blockSize / 2);
    const y = block.offsetTop + (this.blockSize / 2);

    if (this.firstClick) {
        this.ctx.beginPath();
        this.ctx.moveTo(x, y);
        this.setCrosshair(x, y);
        this.firstClick = false;
        this.addPathToDrawSequence(x, y);
        return;
    }

    if (this.isNotOnTheSameAxisAsTheLastInsert(x, y)) {
        if (returnOnFail) { return; }

        this.toggleDrawDirection();
        this.draw(e, block, true);
        return;
    }

    this.ctx.lineTo(x, y);

    this.ctx.stroke();
    this.setCrosshair(x, y);
    this.addPathToDrawSequence(x, y);
}
```

As you can see, I'm applying the '.grid' element over the canvas element. The grid element contains all the blocks that are displayed in flex mode. As you can see the grid container has a display:flex and flex-wrap: wrap properties. In this way, when the user clicks over a block, I can guess the x, y coordinates by getting its position, relative to the parent. Which has the same dimensions as the canvas. Once that I have the x,y coords, i can draw on the canvas.

Comment: Some code would be useful in understanding what you're trying to do. Also, what do you mean by "render in display flex inside the grid element?" Render what exactly? Are you just trying to draw grid lines? Is there any reason why you can't just draw that onto the canvas directly?

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to explain it better, providing some code too :) As you said, I'm trying to draw a grid that I can use to 'snap' the user cursor when it clicks. Using then that clicked block data to calculate the x,y coordinates relative to the parent. And then draw on the canvas. As I said in the edit, the canvas should remain as clean as possible.

Comment: So do you do anything with the divs other than checking if they were clicked? You could just as well add a click listener to the canvas and use some basic math to calculate the position you need without the added overhead of reflowing the divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, creating a multiplicity of DOM elements and trying to dynamically position and size them with javascript will not be particularly performant. I don't think `hr` elements will solve this problem for you.

First, have you considered drawing your grid directly onto the canvas?

Another option is to have a background image with the grid on it layered behind the canvas. This will automatically resize just as performantly as any other aspect of your webpage.

---

Now for the 'snapping' part. It looks like you've already figured out how to draw what you need on the canvas once you get the grid information you're looking for. What you need is a method to get which grid a user clicked on. I'm guessing that is why you overlaid all those divs...

Instead, canvas natively tracks mouse clicks. Using some techniques laid out [here](https://blog.lavrton.com/hit-region-detection-for-html5-canvas-and-how-to-listen-to-click-events-on-canvas-shapes-815034d7e9f8) should be able to get you the grid interaction information you're looking for.

---

**Edit:** A method to generate and find grids:

```js
var height = 100;
var width = 200;
var horizontal_grids = 8;
var vertical_grids = 4;

function bounding_grid_1d(length, grids, x) {
  var divisions = [];
  var grid_width = length / grids;
  
  for ( i = 0; i <= grids; i++ ) {
    if (x || x == 0) {
      if (i*grid_width > x) {
        divisions.push((i-1)*grid_width);
        divisions.push(i*grid_width);
        break;
      }
      else if (i*grid_width == x) {
        divisions.push(i*grid_width);
        break;
      }
    }
    else {
      divisions.push(i*grid_width);
    }
  }
  
  return divisions;
}

console.log("Get all the x and y grid line locations");
console.log(bounding_grid_1d(width, horizontal_grids));
console.log(bounding_grid_1d(height, vertical_grids));


console.log("Get the x and y grid line locations that surround the coordinates (60,30)");
console.log(bounding_grid_1d(width, horizontal_grids, 60));
console.log(bounding_grid_1d(height, vertical_grids, 30));
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, that I'm already reading :) I'd have a question, let's suppose to draw this grid on the canvas, and keeping the draw coordinates in a separated object. Then I could use that grid to detect the click on each separate 'grid square?'

Comment: I'd be inclined to dynamically generate my coordinates. Then I could dynamically determine how many grids I wanted. It should be easy to write the function in such a way that it can return both a sequence of coordinates or return the closest grid coordinates given a coordinate. Let me give you an example in my answer...